# Is there a Karaite answer to the Kuzari?

Tags: sources-mekorot, heterodox, non-rabbinic-judaism

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuzari), the Kuzari was originally written as a reply by Rabbi Yehudah Halevi to a heretic, likely a Spanish Karaite.

Indeed, sections of the book are dedicated to refuting the Karaite views.

I was curious to know whether the Karaites wrote any text that directly refers to the Kuzari and offers up a defense of Karaism in light of the Kuzari's criticism?

Comment: I would call such a thing something from *another* religion. It would be at most like quoting reform.

Comment: @sabbahillel I think Reform are in agreement that they sprouted out of Orthodoxy, whilst Karaites generally believe they sprouted out of one or more non-Rabbinical sects. So, no, I don't think the comparison quite stands. Nonetheless, how is this question different from any other Karaism question on this site?

Comment: I would treat many of the questions about Karaism as I would Christianity or Reconstructionism

Comment: @sabbahillel I see. I suppose it's legit to raise this issue in Meta and put it up for vote.

Comment: @sabbahillel You really shouldn't treat Karaism like Christianity since one is idolatry and one is not [Jewish]. I would treat them like we treat Reform or mystics, wrong or misguided.

Comment: @TurkHill yes I suppose so. However, the way things appear in modern times does seem to be as if many of these different religions are similar in their disbelief. However, that is not a discussion for this forum.